# Why does Unity camera size change when game is maximized in Play Mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[when starting game in focussed mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4mgE.png)

[vs when starting in Maximized mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvF0Z.png)

As you can see the camera size increases when I play maximized mode other than the focussed mode. This problem just randomly happened and I don't know how to fix this, I never had something like this before.

I have triggers on both ends of the camera angle and it's difficult to work with 2 different sizes of camera angles. I already `Debug.Log` the `transform.position` and `transform.localScale` but they did not change after switching to maximized mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed your aspect ratio is set to `Free Aspect`.

[image]

Does it maintain the same camera size if you change it to something like "16:9 Aspect?"

Comment: that was it, thank you so much. I was hella afraid